# How to get 'Sum' working in Calculated field based on another calculation?

Tags: excel, office365, pivot-table, powerpivot, calculated-field

I have a set of data. I need to know if the agent has gone over 25.9 seconds in ACW, if so produce a 1 in the cell, then i want the total number of agents who have bene over this target to be displayed in the subtotal.

So far I have managed to achieve this when its broken down per agent, but my overall either per TM, per month or per week is showing at 0.

[image: my Data per agent:]

[image: When collapsed to show week on week]

as you can see the values are 0. When based on the data it should show 6 for week one, as 6 agents did not hit under 26 seconds in week 1.

I read online that this is due to it working it out based on the row and not what is sat under that. So for example the week 1 overall ACW is 17, so this does go over the 25 seconds, thus giving a 0.

What i want is per agent how many of them went over the 25 seconds in that time period either by month or by day depending on what i choose to then display this total number of agents for the TM or per month or per week.

I have played about with calculated fields and loading the data into power pivot but im not getting what I need.

In power pivot I have used this calculation which works per agent but not per TM or per Week or Per Month.

> OVER 25 Seconds:=IF([IB_ACW]>25.9,1,0)

Could someone please advise me what the correct way to get this to work is?

Thank you in advance! Happy Friday !

Comment: What's the expression for `[IB_ACW]`?

Comment: This is what is used:
IB_ACW:=IFERROR(SUM(DATASHEET[IB_WRAP])/SUM(DATASHEET[IB_CALLS]),0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your `IB_ACW` measure to use `DIVIDE` instead of `IFERROR` and `/` :

```
IB_ACW:=
  DIVIDE(
    SUM(DATASHEET[IB_WRAP]),
    SUM(DATASHEET[IB_CALLS]),
    0
  )
```

You will need to use `SUMX` like:

```
OVER 25 Seconds:=
  SUMX(
    DISTINCT('YourTable'[Agent]),
    IF([IB_ACW] > 25.9, 1, 0)
  )
```

Update the above to the relevant table & column name for Agent.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain but what would i use to work out the percentage of agents not hitting? I tried to use  =DISTINCT('YourTable'[Agent]) to use in a formula along with the over 25 seconds but this comes back with an error.

Comment: Ignore me ive got it working using :
=DISTINCTCOUNT((YourTable[Employee_Name]))